# What sources can help me find ionization energies for solids?

Tags: temperature, resource-recommendations, physical-chemistry, ionization-energy

I am doing a lab experiment (Franck-Hertz) at uni and am supposed to find the temperature, at which electrons are emitted from a barium oxide cathode (without the necessity of an external E-field that provides additional energy). I am attempting to calculate the temperature T = W/k<sub>B</sub> from the **work function W** (i.e. the **ionization energy**).

**Is there any source**, that contains such data? I tried NIST Chemistry WebBook, but they only have data for BaO in the gas phase. I need some value for solid BaO.